# Looping a location-allocation problem in ArcMap's Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, geolocation, loop

I have developed the model below in which I iterate through a series of values for a variable in the Location-Allocation type of problem. The variable is the number of facilities to solve. The model works fine but it is forced to load the facilities and demand points every time it runs.

I cannot figure a work around to use the previously loaded facility candidates and demand points. Since they are always the same this consumes a significant portion of processing time. Does anybody know how to force this variable to change at the "Solve" level?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the input parameters for "Facilities Candidates" and "Demand Points" Are something you don't want to have to enter into the model every time it runs?  If they are always the same then just hard code their paths.

Comment: @GeoJohn exactly, I don't want to load Facility Candidates and Demand Points every time the model runs. How could I hard code their paths in the context of the Model Builder and still allowing the For loop to run?

Comment: @AndréAlho did you finally solved this problem? If you found a solution please share the new model image.

Comment: @mbatsaris as this was almost 3 years ago I can't remember the solution. Also, I don't have an ArcGIS license to open the files. However, I can direct you to some of the final model images in my PhD thesis which can be found in this link (page 146): https://www.dropbox.com/s/nzfygg1zeas7m8x/AA_PhD_Thesis.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple options here.

1.) Make the Road Network feature class a layer and make the resulting layer a prerequisite to the For loop.  Then, inside the iterator, feed that prerequisite layer into a 'Make layer by selection' tool.  At the end of the iteration, clear the selection, and everything should work much better.

2.) Use the whole 'make layer by selection' process before any iteration, then use the 'Iterate Feature Selection', 'Iterate Row Selection', or 'Iterate Field Values', depending on what kind of data you're inputting.